# css z-index divs below another div

Tags: html, css

I'm simply trying to have a line connect a loading bar to a circle.

The line is not being displayed underneath the loading bar however. I've tried messing around with z-indexes and also putting them in containers. Any ideas?

https://jsfiddle.net/sfcurv4h/

```css
body {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #1e1e2f;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.progress {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  justify-content: flex-start;
  border-radius: 100px;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 5px;
  display: flex;
  height: 40px;
  width: 500px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.progress-value {
  animation: load 3s normal forwards;

  border-radius: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  height: 30px;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

@keyframes load {
  0% { width: 0; }
  100% { width: 68%; }
}


.active-services-circle {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #ACACA6;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: background 1s;
}


.active-services-circle.completed {
  border: 2px solid #4B81BD;
  background: #4B81BD; 
}

.space-between-lb-features {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 600px;

  
}

.line-connector {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ACACA6;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="space-between-lb-features">
  
  

<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-value"></div>
</div>
  
 <div class="active-services-circle"></div>


   
 <div class="line-connector"></div> 
  
 </div>
```

Comment: It's because your loading bar has alpha channel set to 0.1, which is almost transparent, so the line is visible from behind of it.

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhhhh -good catch, i thought i was going crazy.